# Front-end в 30 ... не поздно ли?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Всем привет!

Два года назад я впервые познакомился с HTML и CSS, и с тех пор, каждую свободную минуту посвящаю изучению этих технологий. Не так давно приступил к изучению JavaScript/jQuery, кроме того, активно изучаю английский язык.

В данный момент работаю в сфере розничной торговли, заместителем директора магазина, НО всем своим нутром чувствую и понимаю, что это не мое ... и что хочу я заниматься web-разработкой - версткой + JS, именно это мне приносит истинное удовольствие и удовлетворение (в плане трудовой деятельности:)).

Я уверен, что на ХэшКод'e много людей, занимающих руководящие должности в IT-сфере и мой вопрос адресован скорее им, итак:

При таких исходных данных как у меня, взяли бы Вы человека на работу верстальщиком?

Для объективной оценки прилагаю несколько работ которые мне довелось выполнить:

- http://poliarti.ru/
- http://krepezhstroy.ru/

Понимаю, что знаний у меня еще не достаточно, но этот недостаток с лихвой перекрывают: огромное желание работать в IT-сфере, усидчивость, бесконечное терпение и тяга к знаниям.

С уважением, Astor

Comment: @Astor а оправдано ли это с финансовой точки зрения? Призвание призванием, но ведь в 30 лет у вас, вероятно, есть семья. А даже если её и нет, то финансовые запросы существенно выше, чем в 20. Надо полагать, что зам. директора магазина получает более существенные деньги (и имеет более значимые перспективы), нежели верстальщик без опыта. Кроме того, многие потенциальные работодатели (если речь не о фрилансе), будут с подозрением смотреть на вас - дескать, чего это он засиделся до 30 лет в верстальщиках. А в историю про призвание, открывшееся столь поздно, поверит не каждый

Comment: Да, Вы правы, с финансовой точки зрения моя текущая работа куда более выгодная и перспективная, но она не приносит мне удовлетворения. Семья есть и накопления которые позволят мне заниматься любимым делом до тех пор, пока я не выйду на более высокий уровень в IT и не буду заробатывать более приличные деньги, чем заробатывает верстальщик.
Про призвание, возможно, поверит не каждый работодатель, но поверте хотя бы Вы мне, что это именно так.

Спасибо за Ваш комментарий.

Comment: Если только в качестве стажера, уровень представленных не раскрывает потенциал. Для презентации умений хорошо бы взять более сложные страницы: верстка в три колонки, горизонтальное и вертикальное меню, всплывающее вложенное меню, работа с формами, позиционированные элементы и т.д.

Хотя в IT-сфере развитие человека идет долго: [научитесь программировать за десять лет](http://www.williamspublishing.com/21-days.html). Я советую Вам пока не спешить и поднакопить опыт с портфолио. Может стоит посмотреть портфолио верстальщиков на фрилансе.

> P.S. Но осел на krepezhstroy.ru мне понравился ;)

Comment: @Alexey123 а что там за осёл?)

Comment: Кликните по слову Екатеринбург в правом верхнем углу ...

Comment: @Alexey123 люблю пасхалки) А как вы до этого догадались?)

Comment: @DreamChild, на главной (http://krepezhstroy.ru/) вылезает на секунду, при загрузке страницы.

Comment: @DreamChild, просто решил посмотреть как сверстана страница и случайно увидел скрытый блок.

@Astor, да, так действительно проще)

Comment: @Astor это про вашу пасхалку с ослом, что самый простой способ ее увидеть, это кликнуть по Екатеринбургу)

Comment: Понял уже. Осел - это для тех, кто случайно кликнет по Екатеринбургу и у кого с чувством юмора все в порядке ... рад, что Вам понравилось.

Comment: @Alexey123 

     Хотя в IT-сфере развитие человека идет долго: научитесь программировать за десять лет.

По Вашей ссылке: 

     Исследователи (Хейес, Блум) показали, что для приобретения экспертных знаний в любой широкой области человеческой деятельности, включая шахматную игру, сочинение музыки, рисование, игру на фортепьяно, плавание, теннис, а также проведение исследований по нейропсихологии и топологии, требуется приблизительно десять лет.

Норвиг в этом смысле IT не выделял.

Comment: Опыт и знания будут приходить только с практикой. практику можно получить работая в реальной компании, на реальных проектах. В таких условиях квалификация будет расти очень быстро. + советую если фронт-енд, то изучать JS MVC фреймворки, сейчас много вакансий для таких спецов, и уровень ЗП достойный.

Comment: @alexlz, смысл приведения данной статьи не в выделение сферы IT. Смысл в том, что результат зависит от труда и работы над реальными проектами, как там написано, а так же в том, что он не будет виден сразу и для становления может понадобиться продолжительное время. Многие недооценивают время, которое надо затратить.

Answer (score 5):

Я бы не взял верстальщиком. Причина:

Верстальщик это работа не требующая великой квалификации - для девочек и мальчиков - это временная работа. Как правило, люди на верстке не задерживаются и проходят дальше или уходят. Это как бы пехота, которая или погибает или становится сержантом.

Советую сконцентрироваться на чем-то другом. Или дизайн или разработка с привлечением серверных технологий. Из того, что я вижу - вам наверное дизайн более подошел бы.

Возможно, я не прав, поскольку я все таки больше не по фронт-енду, мне ближе серверная часть ну или бизнес-логика.

Comment: @Barmaley, спасибо за ответ! Безусловно, я и не собираюсь всю жизнь сидеть в верстаках, развиваться, развиваться и еще раз развиваться.
Изучение серверных технологий - это следующий шаг.

Для дизайна нужны художественные навыки, которыми я увы не обладаю. Да, дизайн выше указанных примеров мой, но это скорее баловство чем дизайн ...

Comment: я считаю что верстальщик это все таки высоко квалифицированный специалист. У меня есть знакомые которые успешно работают верстальщиками и получают достойные деньги за свой труд.Да и чего далеко ходить, в каждой из компании где я работал есть верстальщики,которые занимаются только своим делом. Задача программистов не мешать им. Каждый должен заниматься своим делом. Другой вопрос что верстальщик не сможет пилить постоянно один проект, он будет работать на нескольких сразу.Я знаю программистов которые не умеют качественно верстать, но это не мешает им быть классными спецами в вебе.ИМХО конечно ж

Comment: Ооо, @Barton, сколько лет, сколько зим ... рад тебя видеть!

Comment: @Astor привет! не мог пройти мимо этой темы, тем более что я видел и скорость и качество твоей работы! Считаю что потенциал есть и достаточно высокий

Comment: @Barton, спасибо за теплые слова! И потенциал есть и желание огромное, принял бы кто-нибудь на работу и я уверен что смог бы себя реализовать и принести пользу компании, но работодатели смотрят на возраст и это очень печально ...

Comment: @Astor, может тогда действительно стоит обратить внимание на фриланс, по крайне мере мне это в свое время помогло. Правда заказы моего уровня и возможностей(я учился на дневном с утра до вечера) появлялись не часто, но все же были. И лучше использовать не самый известный ресурс, например weblancer, что бы была хоть немного меньше конкуренция.

Comment: @Alexey123, спасибо, видимо фриланс в моем случае - единственный шанс попасть в "большой web" ... 

Но ничего ..., я еще помучаю потенциальных работодателей своим резюме :) как говорится - раз в году и вилы стреляют.

Comment: @Astor, в резюме не обязательно указывать возраст. А по закону работодатель не имеет права отказать Вам в работе по причине возраста. По этой же причине сейчас в вакансиях ИТ компаний никогда не пишут желаемый возраст и пол. Попробуйте разместить свое резюме на headhunter. Это единственный вменяемый сайт по трудоустройству, который я знаю. Фриланс я считаю довольно опасным занятием, сегодня у тебя есть заказы, а завтра может и не быть. Тем более человеку без опыта сложно будет на фрилансе.

Comment: @Barton человек который знает только html/css и только начал осваивать JS... Ну как это назвать? У меня сын 12 лет и то чуток знает html/css. При всем уважении к ТС я не могу его назвать *высококвалифицированным специалистом*

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ речь не о конкретном человеке, а вообще о специальности. Вы написали - "Верстальщик это работа не требующая великой квалификации", я не согласен. Качественно сверстать не каждый школьник может, и этому надо учиться.

Answer (score 5):

1. Войти в таком возрасте на рынок достаточно проблематично, если вы конечно не овладели версткой в совершенстве.
2. Фриланс, там никого не волнует 15, 20 или 30 лет, главное сделанная работа. Попробуйте повыполнять задачи, которые там предлагают, «за так», чтобы проверить себя. Если получается и результат удовлетворяет заказчика, начинайте брать деньги.

P.S. 30 лет не так страшны и если вы чувствуете, что «вот оно дело моей мечты», то всё получится.

Comment: @Rubaxa, спасибо Вам за совет, так и сделаю!
Но многие ли заказчики согласятся отдать работу не опытному верстальщику, пусть даже и бесплатно, ведь кроме того, что опыта не много, есть еще основная работа и как следствие, работать над проектом смогу только вечерами/ночами?

Answer (score 5):

Никогда ничего не поздно, бывает не надо. 
В вашем случае я бы сразу занялся серьезным изучением программирования. Не тратьте время на верстку, на ней можно просидеть довольно долго. Тем более, что сейчас хороший фронтенд-разработчик должен (но не обязан) помимо HTML, CSS и jQuery знать очень много попутных вещей, изучение которых может занять существенное время. Для примера, Bootstrap, Zurb Foundation, Less.js, SASS, COMPASS, SVG. Если будете верстать под фреймворки или CMS, то знание шаблонизаторов тоже не помешает. В итоге на изучение и практику всего этого может уйти уйма времени, а фактически Вы останетесь все тем же верстальщиком. Как вариант, можно напирать на JS и уйти в сторону Node.js. Это направление очень перспективное сейчас.

Comment: Спасибо, приму к сведению.
В общем-то я и не собираюсь долго засиживаться с версткой, просто считаю, что работая непосредственно в IT в окружении профессиональных разработчиков, опыт и новые знания придут куда быстрее нежели изучать дома - это как поместить человека в новую языковую среду, изучение языка будет куда эффективней.

Comment: Вообще, планирую более плотно заняться JS ...

Comment: На самом деле это зависит от человека. На работе Вы будете делать в основном свою работу. Человек в большинстве случаев начинает что-то изучать, читать доки, только тогда, когда действительно прижмет.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ для тех, кто будет читать тему позже.

Я полагаю, что тема перехода в IT будет актуальна в ближайшее время для многих, кто не нашел себя в полученных ранее профессиях. Факторов способствующих очень много: это и стабильный спрос на разработку, и зарплаты в среднем более высокие, и упадок некоторых специальностей из-за автоматизации...всего не перечислишь. 
Очень важно понимать, что вы не уникальный случай, таких людей будет становиться все больше. 
Автор совершенно не озвучил очень важные вещи, при приеме решения перехода в IT. Это какой у него опыт с подобными вещами (технического характера), как отношения с математикой, каким образом он развивал мышление, насколько легко и быстро освоил верстку, какой вообще уровень обучаемости.

Абсолютно ничего страшного нет в переходе в IT в 30 лет, если был технический опыт, опыт аналитики, высокая обучаемость и тд, а между прочим такой опыт был у многих. Нужно просто научиться формализовать свои мысли в коде.

Проблема самостоятельного обучения не в том, что человек формально это не может, он просто обычно находится не в том окружении, читает не то, делает не то. Это вопрос эффективности обучения, нужна практика и связка с профессионалами. 
А профессионалы считают, что лучше не надо ему в 30 лет начинать.

А я предлагаю персональные тренировки по фронтенду, карьерные консультации, трудоустройство, стажировки в стартапах.

Comment: @elizavetta, спасибо за ответ!
А можно более подробно по последнему абзацу?
Лучше на mail (адрес указан в профиле).

Comment: >Лучше на mail (адрес указан в профиле)

@Astor e-mail в профиле виден только обладателю профиля